# Showing middle name from three words name using SUBSTRING & CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring

I have a table `MsStaff` consists of few columns. One of the columns is `StaffName`. The `StaffName` data contains two-words-name (like **'Edy Harsono'**) and three-words-name (like **'Dian Felita Tanoto'**). I want to have a column showing the middle name from my staff's 3-words-name (which is **'Felita'**) as the result.

I want to show the result by inputting query using `substring` and `charindex` only.

I've tried this:

```
select [middlename]=SUBSTRING(staffname,charindex(' ',staffname),charindex(' ',staffname))
from MsStaff
```

but it only shows **'Feli'** as the result.
What's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: What are you specifically limiting the query to `substring` and `charindex`?

Comment: So you only want to show the rows where there are three names? Or you want to show all rows but show NULL or something else when they only have two names? What do you want to do about names that seem like middle names but aren't (e.g. `Lisa Van der Hosen`)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is for my homework.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I only want to show the rows where there are only three names. 'Lisa Van der Hosen' is an exception, it won't included into my data.

Comment: Ok so what about `Lisa Van Wyck`? I think your homework assignment is misguided at best.

Comment: @NgFajarChandra . . . It is polite to mention that in the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand 'Van' will be considered as middle name. In this case, the data which my lecturer gives doesn't have any of Germanic surname.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why does it matter if it's homework?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . A natural way to solve this problem is using `reverse()`.  This might be an oversight by someone who is not familiar with string functions, or it might be imposed by some other source.

Comment: @GordonLinoff still don't understand why it matters where the restriction is coming from. The restriction is clearly understood by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

I find the requirements peculiar. One: that the lecturer would ask for a solution that ignores many common elements in names and exceptions to the rules (I have two middle names, I know many people who have none, and I know folks who have two- or three-word last names). Two: that they would constrain you to `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`. Three: that they would ask you for a solution to this problem without having adequately explained to you (or given you the time and resources to learn on your own) how you should approach the problem.

All that said:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(StaffName NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT @t 
SELECT 'Edy Harsono'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dian Felita Tanoto'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Lisa Van der Hosen';

SELECT 
  SUBSTRING
  (
    StaffName,  
    CHARINDEX(' ', StaffName)+1, 
    CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(StaffName, CHARINDEX(' ', StaffName)+2, 255))
  ) FROM @t
  WHERE LEN(RTRIM(StaffName)) - LEN(REPLACE(RTRIM(StaffName), ' ', '')) = 2;
```

Results:

```
Felita

1 row(s) affected.
```

A slightly more clever way, if you can drop the `CHARINDEX`/`SUBSTRING` requirements, is:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(StaffName, ' ', '.'), 2)
FROM @t
WHERE LEN(RTRIM(StaffName)) - LEN(REPLACE(RTRIM(StaffName), ' ', '')) = 2;
```

Comment: My lecturer said that the query doesn't have any `where`. So basically it's just `select` and `from`.

Comment: Well, if you leave out the `WHERE` clause, it is not possible to also satisfy `I only want to show the rows where there are only three names`. You filter out rows using a `WHERE` clause, unless your lecturer is also teaching you magic.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `charindex(' ',staffname)` return the position of the first whitespace, and you are using this position as the length of the substring to get. I guess the problem is around there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select @middleName =
   case When charindex(' ', staffname,  1 + charindex(' ', staffname)) > 0 Then
   Substring(staffname, charindex(' ',staffname), 
              charindex(' ', staffname,  1 + charindex(' ', staffname)) -
                (charindex(' ', staffname))) Else null End
```